# Doctrine combining environmentalism and social services with restrictive immigration and cultural policies

Tags: ideology

As it is right now, as I am aware (which may be lacking), most of the right wing in most of the West is dismissive of environmental preservation and protection and social services, such as single payer healthcare and other safety nets while they are focused on protecting the cultural and demographic profile of their society, to put it that way, through restrictive immigration and other such policies. They are also often inclined towards theocracy, to varying degrees.

On the other side of the conventional spectrum we have the left wing, which often advocates environmentalism and social services but are dismissive of vetting immigration and are open to changing core cultural values according to the trend of the moment. For the most part.

I am just curious whether, either in the U.S. or in Europe, there are movements or political parties that combine environmental protection, secularism and social protection associated with the traditional left with public security and tight immigration of the right?

Comment: Your generalizations are way overly broad to the point where they are a detriment to your question. All the details you mention vary broadly region to region, and some of them are flat out silly. IE I can't think of any major conservative group that wants a theocracy.

Comment: you can ignore the first two paragraphs.  you can focus on my last paragraph, it clearly postulates a question

Comment: besides, i clearly state "most" and "mostly" ...  yet you couldn't wait to accuse me of "generalization".  noting a pattern isn't a "generalization" that postmodernists use as a synonym for discrimination and profiing

Comment: literally none of the right wing wants a theocracy. Religious freedom =/= theocracy. The fact that you say "most" doesnt mean you can get away with whatever generalization you want. Also if you think your first two paragraphs aren't helping you (I would agree) you should take it out.

Comment: "literally none" ? there are nuances to theocracy.  not wearing a T shirt that says "i want theocracy" doesn't mean you don't subtly tend towards it.  e.g. many of Ted Cruz's ideas are theocratic.  anyone who denies the right to choose on religious grounds tends towards theocracy.  i'm done arguing your pedantic rhetoric

Comment: Do you understand what a theocracy is? Ted Cruz is not asking for a religious head to be the head of the United States.

Comment: any infusion of religion and its decrees in politics, giving an indirect political power to clergy is effectively theocracy.  you can mask it however you want.  not having legal abortion is effectively theocracy.  maybe not if you're a theocratic apologist.  just because the head of state isn't a mullah or an ayatollah doesn't mean it is secular

Comment: but regardless, you're being pedantic.  it is obvious that you don't like my post so you're attempting to shoot it down on the grounds of pure syntax whereas the semantics is obvious. you can replace "theocracy" with "religiously biased politics"

Comment: "not having legal abortion is effectively theocracy" Thank you for making my day. I think its clear that we are miles apart on this issue and there is no way to bridge it in these comments. All I can say before these comments get purged is I suggest you read the definition of a theocracy.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I think there are many problems with your post - the theocracy was just the most glaring one. Other problems include `while they are focused on protecting the cultural and demographic profile of their society` - so are liberals and everyone, `dismissive of environmental preservation and protection` - in the US almost all R senators believe in global warming. They may want to kill the EPA, but they still believe in preservation, just not via government mandate. `dismissive of vetting immigration` - not really, they still want security, just not Trump's EO.

Comment: I think that's called "A commune"

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - I can. A a very sizeable minority ([23% in UK](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/apr/11/british-muslims-strong-sense-of-belonging-poll-homosexuality-sharia-law)) of Muslim immigrants wants theocracy, specifically, Shariah law, in European jurisdictions, according, to the polls. Well, except they aren't conservative according to dumb single-axis political alignments, but liberals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the United States, [Steven Hayward](https://www.desmogblog.com/steven-f-Hayward) has advocated for a conservative approach to environmentalism.  In the linked YouTube video below a small group called [BreakThrough](http://thebreakthrough.org/journal), an across the political spectrum of folks that is described as

> Sociologist Daniel Bell once characterized himself as "a socialist in economics, a liberal in politics, and a conservative in culture." It was in part because of his heterodox approach to life that Bell asked original questions and contributed original insights.
>
> Breakthrough Journal exists to modernize political thought for the 21st century.
>
> Founded shortly after the death of heterodox sociologist Daniel Bell, Breakthrough Journal embraces Bell's view that "A new public philosophy will have to be created in order that something we recognize as a liberal society may survive."

You can also check out their mission and how they define ecomodernism [here](http://thebreakthrough.org/about/mission).

See the above link mostly for credentials; [here](http://issues.org/30-3/steven/) and [Can Conservatives be Environmentalists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5x72nipinhw) for more general policy prescriptions from Hayward.

I don't think anyone on the right in the US debates seriously against a either having a welfare state, but to perchance its size, or having a secular, pluralistic society, but rather to freedom of religion.  The rest of your tenets hold true too.

Answer (score -2):

Switzerland, at least the majority of its voters.

I'll take it as obvious assumption (e.g. won't bother proving it) that Swiss are generally more secular, social-safety-net, and environmentally-concerned, than average (definitely more so than average right wing in USA).

Yet,

> **9 February 2014, the federal popular initiative "against mass immigration" was accepted by 50.3% of voters**. The referendum aims to reduce immigration through quotas and limits the freedom of movement between Switzerland and the European Union.